# What is the correct spacing for this Python statement?

Tags: python

I would like to know where the "for i" line should be.  Does it need a certain spacing from the '\' to be valid?

```
kraken_data = {i['name']: ", ".join([host['host'] for host in i['env1'][0]['sins']]) \
        for i in my_dict["aaData"]}
```

Comment: Do you mean purely from a style perspective, or what?

Comment: You do not *need* the "\" for line continuation since it is all inside the dict comprehension

Comment: Do you get a visual warning from your  IDE?